# Firebase task function failed to deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, task-queue

I havae the following firebase cloud function codes and want to deploy to my project.

```
exports.bgTask = functions.region(Defs.SERVER_AREA)
.tasks.taskQueue({
  retryConfig: {
    maxAttempts: 5,
    minBackoffSeconds: 60
  },
  rateLimits: {
    maxConcurrentDispatches: 6
  },
}).onDispatch(async (data) => {
```

});

Obviously, the above code just copied from firebase cloud function sample and it can be run under emulator, but when I tried to deploy to server and had no luck.
I tried to run firebase functions:log command and see the following error log.
[image]

So, it seems that Firebase cli cannot recognize the taskQueue property.
I googled a lot and had no luck. The following screen shot shows the corresponding library what I am using.

Anyone has any ideas on this?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible code including the imports? Check this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, even if you fixed the issue it still won't work because Cloud Function currently supporting `Node.js 16` (recommended), `Node.js 14`, `Node.js 12`, and `Node.js 10` [The Node.js Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime).

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya thanks for reply. Finally, I fixed the problem. First, I tried to create a new project and init firebase functions and deployed successfully. So I tried to figure out what is going on and found that if I re-init the project and firebase cli will prompt that some packages I had installed is too old to deploy the project. So, I went to functions folder and after executing the "npm install --save firebase-functions@latest", everything seems going right!  :D Although it took me whole day to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer? so anyone can benefit from this concern. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Xavier, He managed to fix the issue by creating a new project and initialize Firebase function and deployed successfully by including the packages that are needed and run the command `npm install --save firebase-functions@latest` for the latest version of Firebase Functions.